# How can I find the eigenvectors for this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here is the matrix A:

\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b\\
0 & d \\
\end{pmatrix}

I've been able to find the eigenvalues ($a$ and $d$), however when you put these eigenvalues into the matrix $|A - \lambda I|$

\begin{pmatrix}
a - \lambda & b\\
0 & d - \lambda \\
\end{pmatrix}

the matrix reduces to either a single row or single column. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: For $\lambda = a$, it reduces to $S = \pmatrix{0 & b \\ 0 & d-a}$. That's not a "problem". Can you solve $S\pmatrix{x \\y} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$? Because the solution is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $a$.

Comment: To find eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, solve $Av_1=av_1$ and $Av_2=dv_2$

Comment: Do you want left or right eigenvectors?

Comment: You should be able to find an eigenvector of $a$ at a glance. Recall the meaning of the columns of a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lambda_1 = a$:

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & b \\
  0 & d-a 
 \end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

leads to

$$by=0 \quad\wedge\quad (d-a)y=0$$

which is solved by $y=0$ given that $b\neq 0$ or $a\neq d$. Because $x$ is not present in the above system of equations at all, it means it can be *any* number. So the eigenvector $v_1$ corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
0
\end{pmatrix},$$

which after normalisation gives

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

For $\lambda_2=d$ you'll get one equation involving both $x$ and $y$, meaning that the solution $x$ will be given in terms of $y$ (or vice versa). Then you insert it to $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}$, take out the common factor (i.e., $x$ or $y$) and normalise to get the second eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

when $d \neq a$ we do get two eigenvectors, which I put as the columns of 
$$
E =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & b \\
0 & d-a
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Indeed, we get
$$
E^{-1} =
\frac{1}{d-a}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
d-a & -b \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and $E^{-1}AE = .....$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *of course* that matrix reduces- that's the whole point of an "eigenvector".  That's because the set of all eigenvectors corresponding to a given eigenvalue form a subspace.  There are necessarily an infinite number of vectors.

The **definition** of "eigenvector" of matrix A corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a vector v such that $Av= \lambda v$.  Here, $A= \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}$.  The eigenvalues are a and d.  Any eigenvector, $v= \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$, corresponding to eigenvalue a, must satisfy $Av= \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}ax+ by\\ dy\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}ax \\ ay\end{bmatrix}$.  I would write that as the pair of equations ax+ by= ax and dy= ay.  The first of those reduces to by= 0 so y= 0 which also satisfies dy= ay.  But that does not say anything about x.  In fact x can be anything.  The set of all eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue a is the set of all eigenvectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Similarly the set of all eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue b is the set of all vectors of the for $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ y \end{bmatrix}$.

Added after Christoph's comment:

Boy, I really bollixed that up, didn't I?  I should have said that the eigenvalues are a and d, not a and b.  And an eigenvector, $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ corresponding to eigenvalue d must satisfy $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}ax+ by \\ dy\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}dx \\ dy \end{bmatrix}$ so we have equations ax+ by= dx and dy= dy.  The second equation is true for any y and we can solve the first equation for x= by/(d- a).  Every eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue d is of the form $\begin{bmatrix} by/(d-a) \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ so is a multiple of $\begin{bmatrix} b/(d-a) \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.  But my basic concept is still true- there is not a single "eigenvector" but an infinite number of them- an entire subspace.

Comment: Neither is $b$ an eigenvalue nor is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\y\end{bmatrix}$ an eigenvector (in general).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want right eigenvectors, we are looking for vectors perpendicular to the rows of $A-I\lambda$. A row of the [cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Applications_of_minors_and_cofactors) is perpendicular to all the other rows of the original matrix. Since the rows are dependent, a row of the cofactor matrix
$$
\operatorname{cof}\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\0&d-a\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\color{#C00}{d-a}&\color{#C00}{0}\\-b&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\operatorname{cof}\begin{bmatrix}a-d&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\\color{#C00}{-b}&\color{#C00}{a-d}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore, $\begin{bmatrix}d-a\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-b\\a-d\end{bmatrix}$ are right eigenvectors.